# Could I convert this method using generics?

Tags: java, generics

I currently have the following method in a class which I hope I can push to a superclass since I will have a few other classes which will need similar functionality.

```
public long convertToLong(EnumSet<SomeTypeHere> es) {

  long a = 0;

  for(SomeTypeHere sth : es) {
     a += sth.someLongProperty();

  }
}
```

It would be great if I can do this, I've never really used java generics before other than with collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to put a bound on the generic type. If the class which contains `convertToLong` is parameterized on the same type, you can put the bound there:

```
import java.util.*;
public class GenericTest<C extends GenericTest.HasLongProperty> {
    static interface HasLongProperty {
        long someLongProperty();
    }
    public long convertToLong(Collection<C> es) {
        long a = 0;
        for(C sth : es)
            a += sth.someLongProperty();
        return a;
    }
}
```

Or if the class which contains `convertToLong` is not generic, you can put the bound in the declaration of that one method alone:

```
import java.util.*;
public class GenericTest {
    static interface HasLongProperty {
        long someLongProperty();
    }
    public <C extends GenericTest.HasLongProperty> long convertToLong(Collection<C> es) {
        long a = 0;
        for(C sth : es)
            a += sth.someLongProperty();
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: @newacct, thanks for pointing this out. I corrected the syntax, and added an extra example showing 2 different ways to declare the needed generic bound.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
public <T extends SomeType> long convertToLong(Collection<T> es) {

    long a = 0;

    for(T sth : es) {
       a += sth.someLongProperty();

    }
    return a;
  }
```

This says that you can pass in a Set of type T where T can be any subclass of SomeType and SomeType has the function someLongProperty.

Comment: Why is it a `Set` instead of an arbitrary collection? Do the elements need to be distinct for this technique to be applicable?

Comment: this can be simplified to `public long convertToLong(Collection<? extends SomeType> es) {` and the `for` line to `for(SomeType sth : es) {`

Answer (score 2):

This code below does what you need. The key is the use of the generic syntax that bounds a type to *multiple* types - in this case an Enum *and* your interface.

This compiles:

```
public interface HasSomeLongProperty {
    long someLongProperty();
}

public static enum Fruit implements HasSomeLongProperty {
    apple(1),
    orange() {
        // You may override the default implementation and delegate
        public long someLongProperty() {
            // You could also make this a field and not new every call
            new SomeHasSomeLongPropertyImpl().someLongProperty();
        }
    };

    private long value;

    private Fruit() {
    }

    private Fruit(long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public long someLongProperty() {
        return value;
    }
}

public static <T extends Enum<T> & HasSomeLongProperty> long convertToLong(EnumSet<T> es) {
    long a = 0;
    for (T sth : es)
        a += sth.someLongProperty();
    return a;
}
```

Comment: could the convertToLong be part of HasSomeLongProperty (the super class) somehow, so some variations of the enum could override it if they wanted?

Comment: Unfortunately, enums can not `extend` anything, they can only `implement`. Other than a few restrictions, enums are like any other class, so you could however [delegate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) to some other class. You can also use an anonymous style - see my edited answer for an example.comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Answer (score 0):

yep - java intersection types (Bohemian's answer) do what you want. I had a similar issue where I had a number of enum classes that I all wanted to have a getDescription() method.

In general, intersection types get around the issue that you can't subclass enums.